# Dynamic linq query that Contains ALL from another list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to be able to find all orders with items that contain BOTH apples and oranges that I have in a list.

```
 var itemToFind = new List<string>()
 {
      "apples",
      "cookies"
 };
```

How can I rewrite this so that `Contains` is dynamic?

This returns what I want but how do I make it loop through my list so that it is dynamic?

```
 var query = result
      .Where(o => o.OrderItems
      .Any(i => i.Item.Name.Contains("apples")))
      .Select(x => x)
           .Where(y => y.OrderItems
           .Any(b => b.Item.Name.Contains("cookies"))).ToList(); 
// returns 2 orders
```

Comment: Have you tried to get the "cookies" and "apples" sets separately, and then `Join` the two? You could continue to join to the set of matches in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work but not sure if that is the best way.

```
foreach (var item in listFacets)
{
    // append where clause within loop
    result = result
    .Where(r => r.RecipeFacets
    .Any(f => f.Facet.Slug.Contains(item)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
result.Where(o => o.OrderItems.Any(i => itemToFind.All(itf => i.Item.Name.Contains(itf)))).ToList()
```

Comment: Are you sure you're testing it on the same collections?

Comment: Yes. This seems to work but not sure if that is the best way. foreach (var item in listFacets)
{
 // append where clause within loop
 result = result
 .Where(r => r.RecipeFacets
 .Any(f => f.Facet.Slug.Contains(item)));
}